# Выбрать несколько значений для сессии из БД

Tags: php, сессия

Друзья, как выводить результат сессии, если значения берутся из БД?

Есть вот такая строчка в которой содержатся имена из БД, при получении результата я использую строку
echo $_SESSION['name']; там, где мне это нужно. Но у меня выводится только одно значение из БД, а как вывести все, что есть?

```html
 $_SESSION['name'] = $row['name'];
```

Comment: Для начала надо убедиться, что в сессию вообще надо было что-то класть. Обычно массивы из БД в сессию не кладут. А просто берут из БД, когда нужно

Comment: @Ипатьев это да, но мне нужно сохранить на странице данные, чтобы они не пропадали сразу, а были какое то время.

Comment: Они и не пропадут, они останутся в БД. Их можно в любой момент оттуда достать

Comment: @Ипатьев есть корзина, где выводиться список товаров и когда мне нужно перейти на страницу оформления, я хочу видеть список названий из корзины, но не хочу, чтобы он сразу пропал, если перезагрузить страницу.

Comment: В корзину не пишутся имена. Корзина, в самом простом варианте, состоит из пар  id товара => количество. Для этого элемент массива $_SESSION должен быть массивом.

Comment: вот пример https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1200795/179379

Comment: @Ипатьев у меня в корзине название товара, фотка и количество. На сранице оформление мне нужно видеть то, что было в корзине и чтобы оно не прорпало, если выйду. А как нужно правильно сессию сделать массивом?. У меня не получается, а на минуалах только азы

Comment: @Ипатьев пример видела такой, но так и не поняла

Comment: так тут и нужны азы - добавление элемента в массив. вот в примере как раз оно. вы уж определитесь - или вы ищете пример, или нашли пример, но не поняли его.